# (new) Compiler for (old) XCode

Tags: xcode, gcc

My OS X does not allow me to update to current XCode software.

With the new XCode and iOS SDK, the sourcecode is compiled with a newer compiler which has some new syntax options which are missing on my old platform.

That's why I need your help to get the new compiler to run with my XCode if possible.? Any idea or tip?

OS X 10.6.8
XCode: 3.2.6
I tried any XCode 4 setup, but it worries about the OS X version and does not allow me to upgrade :-(

The feature of the "new" compiler: ARC

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? Which OS X version and which XCode version are you currently running, which XCode or compiler version are you looking for?

Comment: the details can be found in the post now.

Comment: What exactly do you need - for SL 3.2.6 is the last one you can get for free

Comment: I need ARC support. The other features of the IDE don't matter to me, but the syntax of sourcecode with ARC must run.

Answer (score 1):

XCode 4.2 will run on Snow Leopard and it has ARC support.

Go to [Apple Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and search for XCode 4.2 for Snow Leopard, it will show up there, at least if you're a registered iOS developer.

Any newer XCode version than 4.2 is not supported by Apple on Snow Leopard, so I suspect you may have problems even if you'd manage to install it.

Comment: There is only Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS SDK 4.3 for Snow Leopard offered to me. With Xcode 4.2 it is Lion only in the list and search results.

Comment: @ledy id you have only a free developer account then it will not show but surely you have a paid developer account as you need that to publish an IOS app